# getActionMasked() from MotionEvent returns ActionMove masked with some other values. How do I determine these other values?

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, motionevent

I am implementing the stylus button with MotionEvent.

So when I drag over the screen without pressing the stylus button, I will get the following values from getActionMasked(): 0 (ACTION_DOWN), 2 (ACTION_MOVE), and 3 (ACTION_UP)

However, while I hold the stylus button, these motion events give me the getActionMasked() values: 211 (ACTION_DOWN), 213 (ACTION_MOVE), and 212 (ACTION_UP).

The Android documentation says the value for BUTTON_STYLUS_PRIMARY is 32, and that it is not specified as a possible part of the masked value. So why I am getting the masked value of 211, 213, and 212?

I would like to be able to detect regular stylus movement and stylus movement with the button pressed. But I don't want to do something like the following if statement

```
 if (event.getActionMasked() == 213)
```

I would like to avoid using a constant value like 213 because it might change to a different value in the Android source code. Rather, I would like to do it regularly:

```
if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
```

But I need to determine how to unmask 212 to get the actual value of 2. I do not need that extra information because I can simply separately check the button pressed state with:

```
if (event.getButtonState() == MotionEvent.BUTTON_STYLUS_PRIMARY)
```

So what is going on here? Why is the button press altering the ACTION_MOVE value?

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://forum.nomadsculpt.com/t/issue-with-pen-android/243/47 which links https://github.com/Samsung/ChromiumGStreamerBackend/blob/master/content/public/android/java/src/org/chromium/content/browser/SPenSupport.java